# Tkinter: subclassing Button with additional arguments

Tags: python, tkinter, constructor, subclass

I want to subclass Button into OPButtun. OPButton is a regular Button with the capability of writing help messages when the mouse is hovering. OPButton must accept any possible parameter list that thre regular Button constructor would accept, plus two of my own: a message and the Stringvar where to write it in.

This is my code (supposedly runnable)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class OPButton(Button):
    """ """
    def ___init___(self, parent, string, message, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Button.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Enter>", command=lambda e: string.set(message))
        self.bind("<Leave>", command=lambda e: string.set(""))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.str= StringVar()
    OPButton(root, root.str, "hovering the button", text="click here").pack()
    ttk.Label(root, textvariable=root.str).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

and the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\planchoo\oPButton.py", line 19, in <module>
    OPButton(root, "Hello World", "Bouton", text="Hello").pack()
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

**Edit:** Below is the corrected code after Bryan's response. Works at perfection (thanks).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class OPButton(Button):
    """ """
    def __init__(self, parent, string, message, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Button.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Enter>", lambda e: string.set(message))
        self.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: string.set(""))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.chaine = StringVar()
    OPButton(root, root.chaine, "Bouton", text="Hello").pack()
    ttk.Label(root, textvariable=root.chaine).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `__init__()` function you defined was spelled as `___init___()`.

Comment: Thanks. I was not looking in the right direction. I posted the debugged code at the end of the original post. Thanks again. Although the error was as trivial a typo, I was stuck for hours.

Comment: @quickbug No problem. :)